# Python Pandas Add empty column in the middle of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add an empty column after the 3ed column on my data frame that contains 5 columns. Example:

```
Fname,Lname,city,state,zip

mike,smith,new york,ny,11101
```

This is what I have and below I am going to show what I want it to look like.

```
Fname,Lname,new column,city,state,zip

mike,smith,,new york,ny,11101
```

I dont want to populate that column with data all I want to do is add the extra column in the header and that data will have the blank column aka ',,'.
Ive seen examples where a new column is added to the end of a data frame but not at a specific placement.

Comment: Add the column then use `reindex` with `axis=1` to order columns the way you want.

Comment: @ScottBoston what would I use to write this to a new csv file named 'new.csv'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you should use

```
df.insert(loc, column, value)
```

with loc being the index and column the column name and value it's value

for an empty column

```
df.insert(loc=2, column='new col', value=['' for i in range(df.shape[0])])
```

Comment: what would I use to write this to a new csv file named 'new.csv'

Comment: df.to_csv('new.csv',index=False)

Comment: That is exactly what I have but for some reason its not putting out another file.

Comment: import pandas as pd

                                                                                                                           df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\kziaj\Desktop\Python Test\new.csv')

df.insert(loc=1, column='avalue', value=[',' for i in range(df.shape[0])])

df.to_csv('new1.csv',index=False)  #Print in new file

Comment: No im not im using visual studio code off my desktop

Comment: try df.to_csv('C:\Users\kziaj\Desktop\Python Test\new1.csv',index=False)

Comment: It doesnt work I get a unicodeescape codec cant decode bytes in position 2-3 error

Comment: sorry maybe with this df.to_csv('C:/Users/kziaj/Desktop/Python Test/new1.csv',index=False)

Comment: Yes that worked thank you very much. What if I wanted to add 2 different new columns how would I go about that?

Comment: you would use the same method, just insert them in the position you like, please can you mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Use `reindex` or column filtering

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50).reshape(10,-1), columns=[*'ABCDE'])

df['z']= np.nan

df[['A','z','B','C','D','E']]
```

OR

```
df.reindex(['A','z','B','C','D','E'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   z   B   C   D   E
0   0 NaN   1   2   3   4
1   5 NaN   6   7   8   9
2  10 NaN  11  12  13  14
3  15 NaN  16  17  18  19
4  20 NaN  21  22  23  24
5  25 NaN  26  27  28  29
6  30 NaN  31  32  33  34
7  35 NaN  36  37  38  39
8  40 NaN  41  42  43  44
9  45 NaN  46  47  48  49
```

Comment: what would I use to write this to a new csv file named 'new.csv'

Comment: `to_csv('new.csv')` you might want to `fillna('')` and/or `index=False`.

Comment: would you be able to script this for some reason its not creating a new file

Answer (score 2):

You can simply go for `df.insert()`

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Fname': ['mike'], 
        'Lname': ['smith'], 
        'city': ['new york'],
        'state': ['ny'],
        'zip': [11101]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.insert(1, "Address", '', True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Fname Address  Lname      city state    zip
0  mike          smith  new york    ny  11101
```

Comment: what would I use to write this to a new csv file named 'new.csv'

Comment: for saving the df to a new file "new.csv", use  `df.to_csv(filename)`